# Will a 3000/3200 Mhz Sodimm RAM work on my 2933 Mhz Laptop?

Tags: laptop, memory, upgrade

I have an Acer Nitro 5 and it has 2 slots of Ram (1 being used). On the task manager it says it's using a  2933 Ghz RAM. I have read somewhere that 2933 is really rare to find (in fact even impossible) in the market and that a 3000/3200 would still work but will be slowed down to 2933. Is that correct? I'm fairly new at hardware stuffs. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That is correct in theory, but I have not tested it myself. But Linus Tech Tips does have a video about mixing memory and his conclusion was that in dual channel mode (2 sticks) it does not matter most of the times.

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bTS0ybQ3lCI&